# Cross product of partial derivative of vector field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, vector-fields, mathematics

In reading Altland and Simons book (Condensed matter field theory p. 508). I came across the following problem. The authors claim that the term

$$ \partial_1 n \ \times \ \partial_2 n$$

(Where $n(x)$ is a two dimensional vector field defined on $S^2$, the base manifold $x$ is also on $S^2$.)

Is parallel to n itself.

But I doubt it since the partial derivative of the vector field is still in the vector space, so cross product of two partial derivative is perpendicular to the vector space. So I don’t know how this argument is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ is defined on $S^2$, and the *values* of $n$ are supposed to lie on $S^2$. $S^2$ is not a vector space, but its tangent spaces are. However, it makes no sense to take a cross product in those tangent spaces. A cross product isn't even defined in a 2D vector space. So the cross product must mean something else here. I think it has to mean a cross product in a 3D embedding space.

As an explicit example, consider the following field defined on $S^2 $ with values on $S^2$:

$$n=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta).$$

You find that

$$\partial_\theta n=(\cos\theta\cos\phi,\cos\theta\sin\phi,-\sin\theta),$$

$$\partial_\phi n=(-\sin\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\cos\phi,0),$$

and

$$\partial_\theta n\times\partial_\phi n=\sin\theta(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)=n\sin\theta.$$

(Note: I don’t have this book and don’t know condensed matter field theory.)

Comment: Thanks! I made a silly mistake. So the value of n is a subspace of the vector space( $R^3$）,which is not a vector space itself.